# 3d Perspective Carousel not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

I've been working to make a simple 3d perspective carousel that works across modern browsers for a prototype. I found this [codepen](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kiajB) and have been working off of it with much success.

The only issue is in Safari it rotates off of the proper 50% 50% origin:

Container:

```
figure#spinner { 
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  height: 300px; 
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px; 
  transition: 1s; 
}
```

Child images:

```
figure#spinner img { 
  width: 40%; max-width: 425px; 
  position: absolute; left: 30%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
  outline:1px solid transparent; 
}
```

I've gone through [Desandro's 3d perspective carousel tutorial](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html) to try to figure out the issue with no luck.

Anybody have any idea how to get this to work in Safari off of the codepen? Are there webkit specific issues with the way this is set up?